# Select2 on Firefox Mobile with AJAX not selecting touched item

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, firefox, jquery-select2

Select2 with AJAX was working nicely until used on mobile: it incorrectly selects the option above what was pressed. This can't be reproduced using mobile emulator on browser so we think something is interfering with the touch registry on mobile. Issue occurs across different mobile devices.

Have tried to identify problem from multiple respects, look for others having the same problem, no luck. All works beautifully, except on mobile. Minimal example:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
</head>

<select class="form-select" id="custom-select" >
  <option>Christmas Island</option>
  <option>South Sudan</option>
  <option>Kenya</option>
  <option>French Guiana</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {$('#custom-select').select2({
    ajax: {url: 'ajax/example',dataType: 'json',    }
    });});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? What might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I've since found [this is a Firefox Mobile bug with Select2 only when using AJAX](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/5457). It is unrelated to Bootstrap. There appears to be no solution.